# Using a button to display text label

Tags: powerapps

I'm new to Power Apps and am trying to use a button (Button1) that, when selected, displays a text label (TextLable1). I want the text label to be otherwise hidden and only appear when Button1 is selected.

Other solutions provided here haven't worked for me so I'm hoping someone can explain how to do this to a complete newbie like me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Label and update the Visible property to isVisible this is a variable so you can change this to anything really.

Then go to your Button and update the OnSelect with Set(isVisible, true)

On The App > OnStart you can set this variable to false again by Set(isVisibleText, false)

This will allow the label not to be visible when the app starts and this will not work in preview so run the app from the list of your app by hitting Play.

[image]

[image]

[image]